# How to route with django and react

Tags: django, reactjs

I am using django and react together but I dont know how to handle the routing.

```
from . import views
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index),
]
```

That is my urls.py when it loads the html, good and fine it does that well but when I refresh my page in another url (which is in react app) it throws a 404,
I want to this in a way that I will still have my static assets and admin accessible from django.

Comment: You are probably have SPA project. Where js handles routing. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you `js` handles your routing and your server didn't know about that.

So what happens now:

1. when you go to the root page your server receive `/ GET` request. And server send static files. After that your js code works with routes.
2. when you reload your page your server receives `/other-page GET` request. And your server do nothing because you didn't tell server to do something in that case

How to fix:

1. you should return your static files on **ANY** `GET` request
2. if you have API on the same domain you should check for your API `GET` routes first and if it is not an API request you should serve static files